# How to reduce the error in linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

In linear regression, how can we minimize the error term?

Comment: Are you asking about the algorithm used to find the solution; that is minimizes sum of squared residuals?

Comment: Intention here is to reduce the error by all means and considerations.. I know gradient decent is the algorithm that will help here but want to understand, what all elements can be considered here..

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on the comment:

> Intention here is to reduce the error by all means and considerations

- Choice of model: First let's address the obvious assumption: linear regression is a model which requires the response variable to be expressed as a linear combination of the independent variables. In order to improve performance in general one must make sure that these constraints are satisfied. If not it's often worth looking into other models or finding a way to "linearize" the data.
- Data cleaning: depending on the size of the data, linear regression can be very sensitive to outliers. If it makes sense for the problem, outliers can be discarded in order to improve the quality of the model. Of course one shouldn't remove points just because it decreases the error, this has to be done sensibly with respect to the characteristics of the task.
- Feature engineering: it's worth analyzing/experimenting which of the independent variables actually help obtaining a good model. For instance redundant variables may decrease performance. It's also possible that variables can be expressed differently or transformed in a way which improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have two more things to add:

First, try also **interaction effects**, i.e. when you add variables such as:

`y = A*x1 + B*x2 + A*B*x3`

In this way, a new parameter enters the regression to account for the interdependent effects of A and B. It's a trick to move beyond the linearity assumption, and force the impact of one explanatory variable on y as dependent on a third variable. In this way you might capture data in a more nuanced way.

Second, take a close look at **regression diagnostic**. Test for things such as: heteroskedasticity of residuals, normality of variables (and evaluate transformations), uneven influence of observations, etc. Sometimes regressions are underperforming because the dataset they are trained on is not satisfying regression assumptions.